# Simplify radical expression in java

Tags: java, math, methods, square-root

Here is my method so far:

```
public static int[] simplifyRadical(int number) {
    int[] result = new int[2];
    for (int i = 1; i < number / 2; i++) {
        if ((i % number == 0)) {
            //IS a factor of the number in the radical
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The format I'm using is `result[0] = number outside radical` and `result[1] = number inside radical`. So far, my method gets all the factors of `number` (which is the initial UNSIMPLFIED number in the radical). So how can I divide the initial `number` by the perfect square, get the square root of that and multiply that to my `result[0]` variable. Then keep looping until no perfect squares are found. I'm sorry if this question is confusing to read, it was definitely confusing to write. If you need any clarification, please comment below.
**UPDATE:**
So mathematically I am turning: `sqrt(50)` into `5 sqrt(2)` because `sqrt(50) = sqrt(25 * 2)` and 25 is a perfect square of 5, thus: `5 sqrt(2)` is formed.

Comment: It's very confusing :( I have no clear idea from your question of what the output should be. Do you have a (mathematical, perhaps?) definition of what you are after?

Comment: This seems like he's trying to turn things like `sqrt(8)` into `2*sqrt(2)`. I'd rather explicitly extract a list of primary factors, sort it, then look for duplicates which form 'exact squares' under the radical. Duplicate factors can be brought from under the radical, the rest should be left under it.

Comment: I'll suggest that there's not really a meaningful way to do this with a floating point argument.  If the values are integral, it's more meaningful.  You can use integral factorization for the term under the radical and look for duplicates... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization

Comment: I updated my answer to make sense mathematically.

Comment: what is `simplifyRadical(1.1)`?

Comment: dabestharpis's comment: "@Mohit Deshpande Can you please post the entire code?"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you want to simplify a radical. Like, for example, the square root of 99 can be expressed as  3 x the square root of 11.

I'd recommend going about this one of two ways:

---

- 1. Take the square root of n. If n is  a perfect square (i.e. the square root of n has no decimal value), then we just return the square root value with nothing (or a 1) under the radical. Else...
  2. Loop down between the square root of n rounded down to 2. Something like:

     ```
     double nSquareRoot = Math.sqrt(n);
     int squareRootRounded = (int)nSquareRoot;
     //Here goes the first step of the algorithm
     //...
     for (int i = squareRootRounded; i>1; i--)
     ```

     If the counter squared divides evenly into n (i.e. something along the lines of `n % Math.pow(i,2)==0`), then return with the counter outside your radical and n divided by counter squared inside the radical (for example, if n = 99 and the counter is at 3, you'd place 3 outside, and 99/9, or 11, inside). Or in code, once you've determined that i, to the power of two, divides evenly into n:

     ```
     result[0] = i; //Set outside the radical to the counter
     result[1] = n/s; //Set inside the radical to the n divided by s
     ```

     where `s` equals i to the power of two.
  3. If you go through the loop and can't find a perfect square that divides  evenly, then your radical can't be simplified.

---

- 1. Find all the prime factors of a number (for example, 99's prime factors are 3,3,11) (you can find a sample C implementation for finding the prime factors of a number [here](http://wiki.answers.com/Q/Program_in_c_language_to_find_prime_factors_of_a_given_number), which shouldn't be hard at all to adapt to Java).
  2. For every pair of prime factors in your list (like 3,3), multiply the number outside the radical by that prime factor (so for 3,3, you'd multiply your outside value by 3).
  3. For every prime factor that doesn't fit into a pair (like 11), multiply the the number inside the radical by that prime factor.

Hope this helps. If this is completely not what you want at all, sorry.

PS

Even if you go with the first algorithm, you should still take a look at how the second algorithm works, since it is uses [prime factorization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization), a useful technique for doing this by hand.

Comment: This exactly answers it. I just don't quite understand what you mean by "Loop down between the square root of n rounded down to 2"? It is the second point of your first scenario. Could you post a small code sample on how your first scenario would work?

Comment: @Mohit Deshpande I mean loop from the int value of the square root of n. But sure, I'll post an example :-)

Comment: Oh ok, so do you mean: for(int i = 1; i < sqrt(n); i++)?

Comment: @Mohit Deshpande I posted the example. The loop goes the other way around. You loop starting at the floored value of sqrt(n). That way, you find the largest perfect square that is also a factor.

Comment: @Mohit Deshpande I accidentally put -1 in the loop. Fixed now. Your loop should go between the floored value of sqrt(n) to 2, both inclusive.

Comment: Thanks :-) So I got that part down, but what is `n` and `i`? in `n % Math.pow(i,2)==0`? Are they the same counter? Which variable should be multiplied to the outside of the radical and what should be left inside the radical? Could you please post some code for the whole part of step two of the first scenario :-)

Comment: n is number passed as an argument, and i is the loop counter. But sure, I'll post a little bit more

Answer (score 1):

Also if you are using `result[0]` and `result[1]` then your declaration should be:

```
double[] result = new double[2];

instead of

double[] result = new double[1];
```

Comment: I'm sorry, I must have overlooked that!