# Simplify a square root

Tags: java

Let's say that I want to calculate the square root of 8. There are two ways to display the result as you can see here:

[image]

I think that the best way I have to obtain the second solution is this:

[image]

I want to try do display in my Java application 2√2 instead of 2,828427... and so I thought to develop a class following these steps. Let's consider the square root of 8.

1. Get the prime factors of 8 (2*2*2)
2. Count the exponent and try to export them (2^2 * 2 --> 2√2)

I have developed, as you can see below, a code that outputs the factors. If you input 8, the method `estraiRadice()` will output `2 * 2 * 2`, which is correct.

```
private int b = 2;

public String estraiRadice(double x) {

  String resRad = "";
  int[] exponents = new int[100];

  //Scomposizione in fattori primi
  while (x > 1) {

    if ((x % b) == 0) {
      x /= b;
      resRad += String.valueOf(b) + " * ";
    } else {
      b++;
    }
  }

  return resRad;
}
```

The second step is giving me problems because I don't know exactly how to do create the power of a number and export it from the square root. I mean: how can that √2*2*2 become a √4*2 and then 2√2?

I thought that I could store in an array the exponent for each base and then try to export it somehow. Do you have any advice?

Comment: Can you post some code ? and point out where you going wrong. Or you expecting SO to solve it for ya ?

Comment: You can put all prime numbers into a Map. The key is a prime and the value is a degree. Hope it helps.

Comment: what the doce? @asstlias edited the question and added code to it?

Comment: @NoIdeaForName There was a link to pastebin and I just copied pasted the code from PasteBin to the question itself...

Comment: @AlbertoRossi please read on how to create a question. there is the http://stackoverflow.com/help and you SHOULD read on how a question should look like. if you want to i can also direct you to some good question for example.

Comment: Once you have the map with the factors, you just have to multiply the (factors with power/2) (integer part); for square root part multiply the (factors with power%2) (the square root part).

Comment: @GáborBakos Good idea, I'll try to write some code now

Comment: @Alberto: check this 
_[topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5363686/simplify-radical-expression-in-java)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a HashMap to store prime number power pairs

```
HashMap<Integer,Integer> getRoots(int x)
{

    HashMap<Integer,Integer> retval = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
    int i=2;

    while(i<=x)
    {
        int power = 0;

        while( x%i == 0)
        {
            power++;
            x /= i;
        }

        if(power>0)
        {
            retval.put(i,power);
        }

        if(x==1)
        {
            break;
        }

        i++;
    }

    return retval; 
}
```

Comment: first `while` loop seams ideal place for **`for`** loop. You have **initialization** in line above `int i=2`, **condition** `i<=x` and **increment** `i++`

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
public static int[] squareRoot(int number) {
    int number1 = number;
    List<Integer> roots = new ArrayList<>();
    int coefficient = 1;
    for (int i = 2; i < number1; i++) {
        if (number1 % (i * i) == 0) {
            roots.add(i);
            number1 /= i * i;
            for (int j = 2; j < number1; j++) {
                if (number1 % (j * j) == 0) {
                    roots.add(j);
                    number1 /= j * j;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int root : roots) coefficient *= root;
    return new int[]{coefficient, number1};
}
```

You can call it like this:

```
System.out.println(squareRoot(96)[0] + "√" + squareRoot(96)[1]);
```