# How to get square root of a number without decimal places?

Tags: java, android

My question is straight forward that if I want to get a square root of a number say 343, then Math.sqrt gives 18.520.... but my desired output is 7√7.

How can I get it so?

Comment: I think using a third party library like math parser can yield the desired output.

Comment: Check this out:https://github.com/mariuszgromada/MathParser.org-mXparser

Comment: Sorry ... but this is a factorization problem.  So whether or not it "seems inefficient", you need to factorize.  (A third-party library such as the one suggested above will be performing factorization under the hood.  That could well be the pragmatic solution ... depending on the larger context of this specific problem.)

Comment: Check this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27043253/simplify-a-square-root

Comment: @Stephen C what do you think about the code I have posted. I have not done any factorisation in there and it works too...

Comment: That is doing factorization.  The loops were testing to see if i^2 is a factor. And I think it had a bug in it.  Note that factorization is only expensive if the prime factors are really large.  (Try your algorithm for the product of 2 large primes that are close to `sqrt(max_long)` ... then reimplement using BigInteger and try it with some really big numbers.)

Comment: I note that you have changed your question to remove the requirement that the solution doesn't compute factors.  Why did you do that?

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.lang.Math;
import java.util.Scanner;
class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number to get Simplified Square root -");
        long num = sc.nextLong();
        long max = (long) Math.sqrt(num);
        long outsideRoot = 1L;
        
        while (num % 4 == 0){
            outsideRoot *= 2;
            num /= 4;
        }
        
        for (long i = 3L; i < max; i+=2){
            while (num % (i*i) == 0){
                outsideRoot *= i;
                num /= (i*i);
            }
        }
        
        System.out.println(outsideRoot
+"root"+num); 
    }
}
```

I am currently using this code, it seems to work fine until now with some inspiration from Utkarsh Sahu's code. This code executes a lot faster instantaneously while Utkarsh's one took 4-5 seconds which is a huge time considering it is a computer. Thoughts about this code are warmly welcomed in comments.

Comment: Can there be any scenario where this code can give an error if so in which one?

Answer (score -1):

Try out this code snippet.

```
    import java.util.*;
    class SquareRoot{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter the number to be checked");
        long num = sc.nextLong();
        long temp = num, a = 1;
        String root = "";

        for(long i = 2; i <= temp; i++){
            if(temp % (i*i) == 0){
                a *= i;
                temp /= (i*i);
                i--;
            }
        
        }
        root = (temp != 1) ? a+"root"+temp : a+"";
        //In place of writing root, you can use squareroot symbol too
        System.out.println("Square root of "+num+" = "+root);
        sc.close();
    }
}
```

Here in the displaying (printing) portion, I did not have the square root symbol on my keyboard so I couldn't type that and typed "root" instead. You can use the symbol too if you wish.

EDIT: The data types of the variables have been changed from `int` to `long` as per your need...

Comment: Works excellent for smaller number but for bigger ones gives error. Such as in case of 123456123456. I want it for bigger numbers also. Kindly update the code accordingly.

Comment: I have changed the data types as per your need. Now this will work for bigger numbers too....

Comment: Kindly get to me whether it works for you with full satisfaction or not...

Comment: Nope. It is not executing well on a device. I want it to be efficient too but thanks for this atleast it worked for smaller numbers.

Comment: It is now working good and has a better result... @ParitoshTripathi

Comment: Note that this is doing factorization.